# How to avoid the ambiguity of routes in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have three files `server.js, views.js` and `access.js`

In `server.js`I have put all the `dependencies` and some `routes` like

```
app.post('/services/getallversions', (req, res) => {
... 
// code to handle the req and send response
})
```

In `views.js` I have code like below,

```
module.exports = function(app, db, bodyParser, rules, constants, query) {

app.post('/services/user/:user/:type', (req, res) => {
// user can be 'abcd'
// type can be addview, deleteview etc.

...
// do processing for the req and send res
})


}
```

In `access.js` I have code like,

```
module.exports = function(app, db, bodyParser, rules, constants, query) {

app.post('/services/user/:user/:type', (req, res) => {
// user can be 'abcd'
// type can be addaccess, removeaccess etc.

...
// do processing for the req and send res
})


}
```

In `server.js` file I require the `access.js and views.js` in following way,

```
var access = require('./access')(app, db, bodyParser, rules, constants, query)
var views = require('./views')(app, db, bodyParser, rules, constants, query)
```

When I try to `POST` using `/services/user/abcd/addaccess` my `views.js` file code gets executed. `constants, query, rules` are other `.js` file which is already used in `server.js` using `require('./filename')`.

I understand that the ambiguity causes due to *same URL structure*. I am using Express 4 and Node JS 6. I want to separate code of `access.js` and `views.js` from `server.js` and put them in separate files and require them in the above mentioned manner. `views.js` and `access.js` are created by me. They are not any Javascript Framework or something like that.

In `view.js` I have also tried the following code

```
var router = require('express').Router()

router.post('/services/user/:user/:type', (req,res)=>{})
```

But the same problem exists. Is there any way to achieve the thing ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you're asking here. HOW exactly is the server supposed to know whether to run `views.js` or `access.js` code? The URLs are *exactly* the same. You are aware of this problem, but it's impossible to solve without using different URLs, plain and simple. When you include `views.js` _after_ the other file, the `app.post()` call simple overwrites the one in `access.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use "miniApp" concept in Express, where each "miniApp" is distinguished using name-space.

For example: 
Main App:

All routes with '/views/...' prefix will go to viewsCtrl. This middleware should appear before your default/main app routes:

```
 var viewsCtrl = require('./views');
 app.use('/views', viewsCtrl);
```

Inside views.js:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
// complete route /views/services/user/:user/:type
router.get('/services/user/:user/:type', function(req, res){...});
module.exports = router;
```

Same for access.js.

Comment: @ Aman Gupta: Can you please give me the viewsCtrl code? I want to know how to organize the code??

Comment: the second part is viewsCtrl, i have just renamed it while requiring in mainApp.

Answer (score 0):

The routes are identical and express will never be able to tell which one to call. Order is not the problem here; as Chris G said in his comment, the second call to `app.post(...)` will overwrite the first (think of URLs as keys in a hashset).

You already know that the url will be in the format of `/addview` or `/removaccess` etc, so you can put that knowledge in the routing middleware:

```
// access.js
app.post('/services/user/:user/access/:type', (req, res) => {
  // ... type is now only add, remove, etc...
})

// view.js
app.post('/services/user/:user/view/:type', (req, res) => {
  // ...
})
```

or even (I think):

```
// access.js
app.post('/services/user/:user/:type((access)$)/', (req, res) => {
  // ... will match addaccess, removeaccess and so on
  // but I'm not entirely sure ...
})
```

Reference here:

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html